# Swift assert() not working with simple comparison to nil

Tags: swift, assert

This is driving me banerners.

Here's the XCode 6.4 autocomplete from typing `assert` in Swift:

```
assert(condition: Bool, message: String)
```

Here's how I'm using it in my `init`:

```
required init (mainController: MainVC) {
   assert(mainController.parameterThatShouldNotBeNil != nil,
      "oops parameterThatShouldNotBeNil is nil")
   super.init()
}
```

Here's the error message from the little red exclamation point:

```
Cannot invoke 'assert' with an argument list of type '(Bool, String)'
```

...has me pulling my hair out. Double You Tee Eff?

#### EDIT

Here's a short example that can be pasted into XCode:

```
class HasNoNil {
  var definitelyNotNil: String = "nope not nil"
}

class ChecksForANil{
  init (objectToCheck: HasNoNil){
  assert(objectToCheck.definitelyNotNil != nil, "whoops it actually is nil")
  }
}
```

That gives the same error I'm seeing.

Comment: try adding a "message:" before your "oops parameterThatShouldNotBeNil is nil"

Comment: A short *self-contained* example would be helpful. I could not reproduce the problem with a simple class definition. Which Xcode version?

Comment: @Martin_R: my example isn't short and self-contained? edited post to specify XCode 6.4

Comment: @LeMotJuiced: No. Where is the definition of MainVC and parameterThatShouldNotBeNil? The init method is part of which class?  A self-contained example is something that I can copy/paste into an empty Swift file and expect it to compile.

Comment: Martin R is correct. We can never be sure what's wrong if we don't actually copy paste it in our Xcode and compile it

Comment: @MartinR Oh okay I get you. Problem is I just made a short example in a Playground and it doesn't give an error either. Give me a moment to investigate further.

Comment: @MartinR: okay, I made a self-containted example that shows the same error. Good request. I put it in the main post.

Comment: I think this is a misleading  error message; the real issue is that Swift is having problems comparing a non-optional value with "nil", as it can tell at compile time that that's impossible. If you try `if (objectToCheck.definitelyNotNil != nil) { println("Not nil") }` then you get a less misleading error: "Could not find an overload for '!=' that accepts the supplied arguments". (Xcode 6.2/Swift 1.2)

Comment: @MattGibson: certainly _less_ misleading. :) But you nailed it. Thanks. Can you put this in an official answer so I can check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying problem is that Swift can't compare a non-Optional value with `nil`, basically because that comparison doesn't make sense: it's not Optional, so it can't possibly be `nil`, and you can work that out at compile time (or rather, there's no overload for `!=` set up between non-Optional and nil, because there doesn't need to be.)

If you try a simpler example without the assert:

```
class HasNoNil {
    var definitelyNotNil: String = "nope not nil"
}

class ChecksForANil{
    init (objectToCheck: HasNoNil){
        if (objectToCheck.definitelyNotNil != nil) { println("Not nil") }
        // assert(objectToCheck.definitelyNotNil != nil, "Hrm")
    }
}
```

...you'll get a more sensible error: "Could not find an overload for '!=' that accepts the supplied arguments". (Xcode 6.2/Swift 1.2) If you make `definitelyNotNil` an Optional, then everything works fine.

So, I think this is just a misleading error message. Sadly, this type of misleading error, when the problem is with the parameters to a function, seems quite prevalent in early Swift compilers. You might want to try it under Swift 2 and raise a report with Apple if it's not fixed already.